# aggregation on replies and comments with same user in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Imagine we have the structure like the following:

```
comments: [{
    user: '...',
    upVotes: 12,
    text: '...'
    replies: [{
        user: '...',
        upVotes: 34,
        text: '...'
    }]
}]
```

what we want is to retrieve the user and text of comments and replies with the same user!
I have implemented the following query but it doesn't work:

```
db.getCollection('links').aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$comments"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$comments.replies"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            sameAuthor: {
                $eq: ["$comments.user", "$comments.replies.user"]
            },


        }
    }


])
```

I don't know where the problem is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need more clear result please add result sample in the comment.

```
db.links.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$comments'},
    { $unwind: '$comments.replies'},
    { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$comments.user", "$comments.replies.user"] } } },
    { $group: { 
        _id: '$_id',
        user: { $first: "$comments.user" },
        commentText: { $first: "$comments.text" },
        repliesTaxt: { $push: "$comments.replies.text" }
        }
    }
])
```